# Erro em tempo de execução '13'

Tags: vba

Estou criando uma macro para apagar  os valores da celula que contem #N/D, mas ele me da apresenta (Erro em tempo de execução '13')

Quando coloco #N/A o codigo funciona.

Alguem pode me ajudar a solucionar o problema?

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'percorre da linha 2 até a última preenchida em A
   For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'se em B for #N/D
    If Cells(i, 2) = "#N/D" Then
    'apaga conteúdo de A
    Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
    End If
  'próxima linha
 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Você pode formata o texto de sua pergunta para que possa ficar melhor de entender.

Comment: @DoutorStephenStrange ficou melhor ?

Comment: Ficou muito Show!!!

Comment: @DoutorStephenStrange  o excel nao aceita #N/D  como um valor, quando faço a execução do codigo ele me apresenta um erro chamado: 
" Erro em tempo de execução '13' "
Mas se mudo o #N/D para qualquer outro texto exemplo #N/A ele aceita.

Comment: Velho é não entendo de vba mais, calma aguem vem te ajudar o, pt.stackoverflow.com tem muitas pessoa que podem fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [isNA()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-isna-method-excel)

#### Código

```
'percorre da linha 2 até a última preenchida em A
   For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'se em B for #N/D
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(i, 2)) Then
    'apaga conteúdo de A
    Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
    End If
  'próxima linha
 Next i
```

#### Erro

Este erro ocorre porque #N/D não é uma String, mas sim uma variável de erro. Por isso a função `isNA()` é usada. Porém, #N/D pode ser procurado com funções simples de procura de String, como o `.Find`

#### Outro modo

É realizado utilizando a função [CVerr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/cverr-function)

```
'percorre da linha 2 até a última preenchida em A
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'se em B houver erro
    If IsError(Cells(i, 2)) Then
        'Se em B for #N/D
        If Cells(i, 2) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
            'apaga conteúdo de A
            Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
    'próxima linha
Next i
```